# How can I remove these trash items / Why these things don't disappear?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

[image]

I always "take all" from corpses
-> Too many items
-> And here is where I drop trash items
-> Result...

Comment: I think you have a hoarding problem...

Comment: If you drop them in a non-respawning cell, you're out of luck. You'll have to pick them all up if you want to do anything with them (short of mods, perhaps).

Comment: I want to do this now after seeing this glorious pile of junk

Comment: LOL so much you can FUS RO DAAH them!

Answer (score 5):

Take them and sell them to a trader or put them in a respawning container (in a random cave somewhere or some such place). Dropping items in a non-respawning cell means they will stay there.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I just clean up them by collecting ALL of them, and drop them to my house's big lake.
FYI, this took nearly one hour(real life).

After that, I found that I can't swim into the house's lake anymore(PC crash into desktop when I go into the lake). Too bad :(

Now, I'm moving my garbage items to imperial camp's chest :P
(I'm not imperial side, guards are attacking me. I give them a "gift".)

> What room is so big to fit all this junk? –  Vaishali
>   That room is not mine.
>   Hint: Windhelm, Right-Below's house, 1F

Answer (score 2):

@Falskaar, Go clean your room!

Open the console and aim for your pile of junks, and use this command:

`MarkForDelete` Permanently deletes the selected item either instantaneously or upon reload. This command is cleaner than disable, as it removes the item completely instead of just hiding it from view.

And repeat for all items in the pile.

Comment: I think that may be unfeasible for that amount of stuff.

Comment: seriously, It will take like 20 minutes. The console's auto aim gives the id of the aimed object. Just hit the up arrow to repeat last command and batch it.

Answer (score 1):

A long answer incoming!

The code of Skyrim is such that any object in the game existed always and will exist forever. New objects can be created in-game, items that can be bought, for example. Enchanted weapons and apparel can be destroyed but not the ordinary ones. If any item is dropped anywhere in the world, it'll stay there forever.

However, there's a way to get around this: Using the console that is built into the game. The `MarkForDelete` command does the job just fine. To open the console, press <kbd>~</kbd> key(just below <kbd>Esc</kbd>).

However I think it's better to keep them in cupboards and chests. The `MarkForDelete` command is irreversible. Once gone, is gone forever. It sets a permanent flag on the object's code asking the console to never render and scripts to never include it in the game. Chests, cupboards, end tables, etc. are "bottomless". You can store the things in chests and make money out of them when you don't need them.

If you become a Thane in Riften, you'll already have bought a home, probably with a chest or you can store all the things in the cupboard beside your bed in Jorrvaskr.

You may accidentally delete the code for a cell or a room while using `MarkForDelete`, and it is irreversible. Hence, it is always to wise to keep things. I use multiple cupboards and chests to organize the collected things. I put all the weapons in chest, armor in a closet, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, certain items can't disappear. I suggest:

1. Putting all the items in a chest [A chest has unlimted inventory space, so don't worry].
2. Using cheats. Type `disable` or `MarkForDelete` for each item you don't want.
3. Drop them in a respawning cell.
4. Drop them in someone elses house and let them live like, no I don't want to live like this [Related to 3]!
5. Give your items to a follower. Since you can't give all the stuff to the follower using trade, command him/her to pick those items up.
6. Sell all those items up. if they run out of money, wait 2 days, otherwise, save, kill, reload, sell, repeat.
7. Fus Ro Dah them to make your house go crazy [Don't listen, just joking].
8. Put all the items in a room you don't use in your house.
9. Put all the items in an area no one will look at, such as the lake.
10. Put them in the Gray Quarter, let those Dummer get what they deserve since Nords are racist.

Answer (score 0):

A portable trashcan may be useful, so try this one https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/19458

From the mod description:

> Mod adds a Bag of Trash to your inventory that you can open & toss unwanted junk away in. You can also adjust the bag's settings to pay you a % of the junk value. Items get removed cleanly from the game world (and your save file), and you make some coin on the side.

It still takes some time to junk stuff, but at least you can clean the inventory and have money back.